# Scrape data from flash only site

Tags: flash, screen-scraping, scrape

I know a bit of javascript, HTML, CSS, VBA and just general programming structures (functions, loops, etc.)

How would you approach this problem. A sports betting website posts numerical data (odds) on its flash only website. The betting odds change very frequently.

I need to get this data. Preferably by scraping the data each second, putting the data and the timestamp in text file.

They use RMTPS protocol to send the data to my browser. So packet listening is impossible? I am a n00b so forgive me I am wrong.

I know pixel scraping is possible, but its a pain in the a**holes to get it to work.

I saved the website. I reverse engineered the swf file into fla file. I think I have the complete source code of the site. Its rather big. Fortunately the code is very descriptive and readable, but still enormous.

The question is, how can I get the data not by pixel scraping or packet sniffing, but by intruding and "listening" to the data stream and capturing the data I want?

I am pretty sure there is NO function like getOddsGameID(223) or something. I think the betting odds data transfer may be initiated by the server and not from some timed function within script itself. So I need to sort of pretend I am a browser and get the raw data before it goes into flash interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try using Adobe's swf2html tool to extract the strings. It may get you what you need, although I haven't had much success with it.